# What is a "cut it up poster"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I heard this line in a film's audio description:

> There are numerous photos of Tris on his bedroom wall, including a cut-it-up 1940s poster featuring both Nick and Tris with the slogan "homies forever".

Google search results don't seem to suggest "cut-it-up" poster is a thing. The poster in the film is an ordinary poster with a photo of Nick and Tris embedded in a wall background, like the ones found in [Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=homies%20forever%20poster&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNmqSixOPeAhXjRd8KHWMoCIgQsAR6BAgDEAE&biw=1920&bih=970#imgrc=RjztjIi2PDsePM:). The closest description I would use is cutout.

I am not sure if I heard it wrong. I am putting a [recording clyp](https://clyp.it/bsdt1u0q) here for context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something which is **codded up** is not genuine. It's a kind of fakery or hoax, e.g. "Photoshopped".